# Answer on a question no longer valid

Tags: discussion, answers

I just ran across this answer doing edit approval.   It appears that the accepted answer on the question is no longer valid as the site it points to no longer exists.

[Having an online highscore leaderboard for a Flash game](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668411/1841839)

I was just wondering what we do with something like this.  It's the accepted answer can we / should we remove it?

I have added a comment to the answer stating that it no longer works.  But I thought I would ask here to get an idea on how we treat issues like this.

Comment: I voted to close that question you linked to. It basically is asking for a site recommendation which attracts link only answers as is proven by the other answers...

Answer (score 7):

If you can, improve the answer by fixing the broken link to the new location of the same content.

If that is not possible leave a comment for the author, maybe he/she knows a mirror of that original content.

Downvote the accepted answer.

Provide a new answer, preferable without a link or with the essential parts of the content the link provided copied in the post with proper attribution.

That answer shows why we [don't like the answer to be in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

More often than not those answers are given on questions that are asking for libraries, off-site resources or recommendations. Those questions should be closed, either by [flagging or voting to close them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow).