# How to deal with an accepted answer which is no longer valid (asking to reconsider it)?

Tags: discussion

A [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3) has an answer which used to be good but is not anymore (the site linked to specifically informs that the solution is deprecated).

Is there anything specific to do beside leaving a comment (which I did), particularly when another existing answer solves the problem correctly? I tried to reach to the OP but there are no contact information available.

Note: there is [a very similar question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251951/answer-on-a-question-no-longer-valid) which I do not feel being an exact duplicate because in my case there is a perfect answer already existing, the accepted one is not correct anymore (and has been accepted in good faith at the time) -- *what is just missing is the ability to ask for a reconsideration of the accepted answer*.

This said, if you feel this is a duplicate feel free to close my question.

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing you, or mods, can do concerning which answer is accepted.

Comment: If you have added a comment to say you feel another answer is better, then new readers will see that. It's worth [reading this recent question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284809/472495) too, about the "wrong" answer being accepted.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking at a wrapper for legacy packages, I can't see anywhere where it says that the wrapper itself is deprecated.

However, the answer to the question is "do nothing". The accepted answer is only obsolete if you are [using Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211599/458741). If you're on 3.3 then it's not necessarily obsolete.

Other users have done *exactly* the correct thing and have written up later answers that mention specific versions. These answers are now more highly voted than the accepted answer. The system works!

If you think that the highest voted answer should be sorted above the accepted answer go and upvote [Order highest upvoted answer before accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/order-highest-upvoted-answer-before-accepted-answer)